# How to do performance testing of OTP authentication in JMeter

Tags: jmeter, okta

We have an application and it's having okta authentication . So after we enter our credentials, an OTP is being sent to our gmail address and we have to give that OTP to login. How to record these steps in JMeter, or how to do the performance test of these kind of applications?

Answer (score 1):

You can get the email sent to Gmail account via JMeter's [Mail Reader Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Mail_Reader_Sampler), the setup would be something like:

[image]

Once done you can fetch the OTP from the email body using a suitable Post-Processor like [Regular Expression Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor) or [Boundary Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Boundary_Extractor)

More information: [Load Testing Your Email Server: How to Send and Receive E-mails with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/load-testing-your-email-server-how-send-and-receive-e-mails-jmeter)

You may also need to [enable access of less secure apps](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en) to your google mail account

Answer (score 0):

Actually, when I debugged the application and checked the console, I found that the OTP UI is just a wrapper above a token service. So what I did was to replace the okta authentication samplers from the recording by that token service. I kept all the remaining samplers intact. And extracted that token from token service and passed it on to the header manager of the remaining samplers. This was accepted by our team too. But if we really have to do a performance test on the okta authentication, still we can ask the dev to create an OTP that wouldn't expire in another 24 hours or so, so that we can use that and load test the authentication samplers too.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).